# Converting object name to a string in a list in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I couldn't seem to find an answer that worked but essentially I am looping over models I have created and I am aiming to output the accuracy along with the name of the model as shown below:

```
  accuracy_data <- function(model_prediction,model_name){
     confmat <- confusionMatrix(model_prediction, test_data$DEATH_EVENT)
     accuracy_results <- round(confmat$overall[["Accuracy"]]*100, digits=2)
     print(paste(model_name," - ",accuracy_results,"%",sep=""))
     }
  pred_list <- list(log_pred,knn_pred,svm_pred,non_svm_pred,tree_pred,rf_pred,gbm_pred,xgb_pred,nn_pred)
  for(predic in pred_list){
     accuracy_data(predic,"Model Name")
     }
```

The output is as follows:

```
[1] "Model Name - 83.05%"
[1] "Model Name - 86.44%"
[1] "Model Name - 83.05%"
[1] "Model Name - 83.05%"
[1] "Model Name - 86.44%"
[1] "Model Name - 84.75%"
[1] "Model Name - 91.53%"
[1] "Model Name - 89.83%"
[1] "Model Name - 86.44%"
```

I can't find a way to replace "Model Name" with the name of the model in each case. Is there a simple way to do this? Either using the pred_list names or some other way?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I did have a search on google and on here before asking but with no success!

Also an extra question - is there a way to output these results into a table or array of some kind rather than as is? (Sorry if this should be a separate question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a `named` list with `list(log__pred = log_pred, ...)` or more easily with `dplyr::lst` or `purrr::lst`

```
pred_list <- dplyr::lst(log_pred, knn_pred, svm_pred, non_svm_pred, tree_pred,
           rf_pred, gbm_pred, xgb_pred, nn_pred)
```

Then, loop over the `names` of the 'pred_list'

```
for(nm in names(pred_list)){
    accuracy_data(pred_list[[nm]], nm)
 }
```

---

Regarding the output, it is just `print`ing i.e. there is no return value.   If we need to create an object, then inside the function we could change the `print` to return an output

```
accuracy_data <- function(model_prediction,model_name){
 confmat <- confusionMatrix(model_prediction, test_data$DEATH_EVENT)
 accuracy_results <- round(confmat$overall[["Accuracy"]]*100, digits=2)
 return(paste(model_name," - ",accuracy_results,"%",sep=""))
 }
```

and then create a `vector` to store the output and append the output

```
out <- c()
for(nm in names(pred_list)) {
    out <- c(out, accuracy_data(pred_list[[nm]], nm))
}
```

Comment: Brilliant this answered my questions perfectly. I do have another question (though I can make it a new question). If I wanted to actually use name of the model such as 'Logistic Regression' instead of 'log_pred' as in the model object name are there any simple options? like a dictionary of some sort?

Comment: @Jonas_Konig can you please post as a new question.  Thanks.